# Error: Unknown column 'Maslulim' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

My code is given below:

```
    $pullGroupNamesSQL ="SELECT 'Group name' FROM `requests` WHERE 'stage'=$stageID"
                        . " and 'date'='2014-03-18'";
    $pullGroupName = mysqli_query($con, $pullGroupNamesSQL)
                or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
```

When I try to run this query I get this error:

```
Error: Unknown column 'Maslulim' in 'where clause'
```

I checked alot (!!!) in the web and couldn't find the answer to this...

Comment: You need to quote `$stageId`. Also this kind of select is dangerous (sql injection)

Comment: That's a good point, `'Maslulim'` is the contents of `$stageID`.

Comment: Column name should be enclose in a backtics ` & not in a single quote `'`.

Comment: Use backticks for all column names, and not single quote.

Comment: 'Group name', 'stage' and 'date' have string quotes, I assume they are columns and need to be quote with (`) instead of (')

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"SELECT Group name FROM requests WHERE stage= ".$stageID." and date='2014-03-18'"
```

Comment: my stage id is `'' OR 1=1--`.. and you're missing a space before `and`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$pullGroupNamesSQL = "SELECT column_name FROM Table_name WHERE stage='$stageID' AND date='2014-03-18'";
```